# Making referrer and querystring available to a frame under a different domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, frame

I need to deal with a website that is just a page with a big frame that loads all the website content. I can't change this.

```
<html>
    <!-- this page lives under mydomain.com -->
    <head>
        <title>My Beautiful Website</title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%" border="0" frameborder="0">
        <!-- website actual content is loaded from a subdir of a completely different domain -->
        <frame src="http://mydifferentdomain.com/subdir" name="my-ugly-frame">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

I need to make the referrer and query string informations of mydomain.com, available to the javascript code that runs **inside** the frame, so I can understand how people reach this website.

Is there a way to circumvent cross domain restrictions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add JS code to the frameset page?

Comment: so build the frame source URL with JavaScript.. done that with `iframe` so guess it should be possible for ordinary frame as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to circumvent cross domain restrictions?

No. The data has to be passed explicitly.

The frameset page could include the data in the query string of the URI used to load the embedded page … but I'm guessing that this is domain hosting for the DNS server deprived and that that isn't an option.